# Stationary distribution of Markov chain with continuous state space

Tags: normal-distribution, markov-process

I'm considering a Markov process with a continuous state space. Let $V(x)$ be a differentiable function, $\Delta t$ a fixed time step, and, at every step, set

$$x_{n+1}= x_n-\alpha \frac{dV}{dx}\Big|_{x=x_n}\Delta t +\beta \xi_n \sqrt{\Delta t}$$

where $\xi_n$ are independent Gaussian variables with unit variance and zero mean. Assuming that $\Delta t $ is small, I'm looking for the stationary distribution.

I found that

$$\rho(x_{n+1}|x_n) = \frac{1}{2\beta \sqrt{\pi \Delta t}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\frac{x_{n+1}-(x_n-\alpha V'(x_n)\Delta t)}{\beta \sqrt{\Delta t}}\big)^2}$$

Letting $\pi(x)$ be the stationary distribution, we then have that

$$\pi(y) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \pi(x)\rho(y|x)dx $$

The detailed balance condition tells us that

$$\pi(y) e^{\big(\frac{y\alpha V'(y) -x\alpha V'(y) +\alpha^2(V'(y))^2\Delta t}{\beta^2}\big)} = \pi(x) e^{\big(\frac{x\alpha V'(x)-y\alpha V'(x) +\alpha^2(V'(x))^2\Delta t}{\beta^2}\big)} $$

but I'm not sure if this is helpful. There's also some helpful information [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423371/can-we-calculate-the-theoretical-stationary-distribution-from-a-continuous-marko). Maybe you do something along the lines of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720382/integral-of-product-of-two-normal-distribution-densities) post?